# Clear history and referrer data in PHP and JS?

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a PHP file say `notracking.php`, all I am trying is where ever visitor will go after this page that site should not be able to track previous page from where visitor came. Please tell what is missing; so far I have made this file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
location.replace('http://example.com/fake-link');
</script>

<?php
//example.com shouldn't be able to track from where visitor came
header( "Location: http://example.com" );
?>
```

No problem if example.com tracks visitor came from `http://.../notracking.php` but it should not have any tracking about anything before it.

If visitor flow is:

`.../somepage` **>** `../notracking.php` **>**  `example.com`

**example.com should not be able to track** `.../somepage` **by its front-end JS or back-end**

Comment: From ".../somepage" you have a link to "example.com" or to "../notracking.php" ? Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: `/somepage` will have a link but it is engineered to go through `notracking.php` like `notracking.php?url=example.com`

Comment: Ok so... if you go from `.../somepage` to `example.com`, once you go to `example.com` you want to remove `.../somepage` from browser history?

Comment: Exactly Walter, example.com should not be able to find referrer. The best logic I happened to find is introduction of `notracking.php` file; which can be tracked but should erase anything before it. But you are welcome to provide any alternate logic.

Comment: OK, I'll post you an update in my anwer.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side language. You can't tell to the browser to ignore the previous page. You can do it with location.replace in Javascript.

As you mention:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
location.replace('http://example.com/fake-link');
</script>
```

You can write this in your PHP file:

```
<?php
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>
location.replace(\"http://example.com/fake-link\");
</script>");
?>
```

If you go from `.../somepage` to `example.com` and once you go to `example.com` you want to remove `.../somepage` from browser history you can use the JS method in `.../somepage` by doing this:

```
<a onclick="gotosite('http://example.com/fake-link')">LINK TO example.com</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function gotosite(url)
{
location.replace(url);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am not asking for PHP ONLY answer, that is why in file code snippet I added both javascript and php sections and also I have tagged javascript in question.

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb. The redirect `header( "Location: http://example.com" );` itself deletes the trace of referrer nothing else is needed.

Comment: But you can't push that code once the page was loaded so you need to do it with JS. If you need to do this "as a link" this is the best solution.